# Looped GIF or video in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, gif

Is it possible to

A, **embedding an animated GIF**, or
B, **embedding a video where the controllers are hidden and loops itself automatically**

within InDesign, then export it as an interactive PDF?
Is there any script to do that?

This would be very useful in a presentation.

Comment: Did you try embedding a gif or a video in InDesign and exporting the file in an interactive PDF? Seems like there's a few tutorials http://goo.gl/3yrMau

Comment: ... I tried it, yes, what do you think, why do I ask? You can't export PDF with animated GIF. And you can't export PDF with a video where the controllers are hidden and the video loops itself automatically.

Answer (score 3):

> *"You can't export PDF with animated GIF. And you can't export PDF with
>   a video where the controllers are hidden and the video loops itself
>   automatically."*

Unfortunately I haven't test the Indesign interactive PDF but you could have a look at exporting in ePub.

---

**Another option is to create your PDF as you normally do and add your videos directly in Adobe Acrobat Pro.**

Not the most practical way of doing it if you have a lot of revisions on your documents but it's fast to add them.

[image: Add video for interactive PDF]

**You have the option to hide or show the controls on your videos as well, and it works perfectly fine.**

[image: Add video without the controls in Adobe Acrobat Pro]

**The content can play if clicked or when the page is opened. It doesn't automatically loop.**

If you wanted to make it loop you'll need to look at the settings or maybe convert your video or animation in flash.

[image: Autoplay video in Acrobat Pro]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Well, I tried that already, the main question is the looping. I found a script earlier, that you have to put in Adobe Acrobat's folder, but it didn't work.

Comment: If you can use a swf it should loop by default. Otherwise you might need to add a script at the end of your animation to make it loop.

Comment: Can you help me with this script?

Comment: I'm really not a pro at script. What kind of file are you trying to insert (extension)? Is it a movie, animation?

Comment: GIF or H.264. They are just sort animations, showing (for example) changes on a logo design.

Comment: Can't you simply convert these gif to swf? You don't even need to use any software, there's lot of free converter online, like this: https://cloudconvert.com/gif-to-swf  The swf doesn't give you the option to hide the control but the "play" button doesn't appear unless you mouseover the video... and that's the only control you'll see (no timeline) Example: http://i.imgur.com/VAgeMBP.png

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible include animated content in an Interactive PDF.

However, three other formats that can be exported by InDesign support some version of looping content:

- Animated GIFs (supported by FXL Epub, Publish Online, in5 HTML)
- Looped Video (FXL Epub, Publish Online, in5 HTML)
- Multi-State Object Slideshow (in5 HTML)
- Image Sequences (in5 HTML)
- [Looping InDesign animation](https://ajarproductions.com/blog/2017/02/20/how-to-create-a-looping-html-slideshow-with-indesign-and-in5/) (in5 HTML)

Main source: https://indesignsecrets.com/animated-gifs-indesign.php

Animated content is not supported in an Interactive PDF. Video was previously supported using the Flash Player (now defunct) inside of Acrobat/Reader.

More info on Interactive PDF:
https://ajarproductions.com/blog/2018/03/26/interactive-pdf-is-dead-heres-what-you-can-create-from-indesign-thats-even-better/

Disclaimer: I am the creator of in5.